# Prove that Lie bracket and Lie derivative satisfy $[\mathcal L_X,\mathcal L_Y]=\mathcal L_{[X,Y]}$, for all vector fields $X,Y$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, lie-derivative

I'll provide an incomplete solution for the following exercise.

**Exercise**

$(i)$ Let $X$ and $Y$ be two vector fields. Prove that

$$[\mathcal{L}_X,\mathcal{L}_Y]=\mathcal{L}_{[X,Y]}.$$

$(ii)$ Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three vector fields. Prove that

$$[[\mathcal{L}_X,\mathcal{L}_Y],\mathcal{L}_Z]+[[\mathcal{L}_Y,\mathcal{L}_Z],\mathcal{L}_X]+[[\mathcal{L}_Z,\mathcal{L}_X],\mathcal{L}_Y]=0$$

**Solution (incomplete)**

First of all, I'm trying to figure out what I actually need to prove. The two members on the left and on the right of the first equality are *operators* (they act on vector fields), not vector fields. So, in order to prove that they are equal, I need to prove that they are equal *when applied to a generic vector field*. The operator on the left is intended to act on a vector field $Z$ this way

$$[\mathcal{L}_X,\mathcal{L}_Y](Z)=[\mathcal{L}_XZ,\mathcal{L}_YZ],$$

am I right?

I know that $\mathcal{L}_XY=[X,Y]$, so it's all about proving that

$$[[X,Z],[Y,Z]]=[[X,Y],Z].$$

At this point I tried to do a little calculations (applying the definition of Lie bracket and its properties) but I'm stuck. I simply don't get the same thing on the left and on the right.

The second point, *as soon as one has proved the first*, is quite easy (it amounts to apply the first point and the Jacobi identity).

Any ideas for the first point? Thank you

Comment: You've got the formula for $[\mathcal L_X,\mathcal L_Y](Z)$ wrong. It should be $\mathcal L_X(\mathcal L_YZ) - \mathcal L_Y(\mathcal L_XZ)$. Now expand that out in terms of Lie brackets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The operator on the left is intended to act on a vector field $Z$ this way$$[\mathcal{L}_X,\mathcal{L}_Y](Z)=[\mathcal{L}_XZ,\mathcal{L}_YZ],$$
>   am I right?

No. As Jack Lee commented, it should be

$$[\mathcal{L}_X,\mathcal{L}_Y](Z) = \mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_YZ) - \mathcal{L}_Y(\mathcal{L}_XZ).$$

Now

\begin{align}\mathcal{L}_X(\mathcal{L}_YZ) - \mathcal{L}_Y(\mathcal{L}_XZ) &= \mathcal{L}_X([Y,Z]) - \mathcal{L}_Y([X,Z])\\
& = [X,[Y,Z]] - [Y,[X,Z]]\\
&= [X,[Y,Z]] + [Y,[Z,X]] = \cdots\end{align}

Complete the calculation using Jacobi's identity.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot prove the identity
$$
[[X,Z],[Y,Z]]=[[X,Y],Z]
$$
for Lie algebras, because it is not true. You have tried to do a little calculation; so you were already almost there, just trying a little example, say, for
the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, with basis $(X,Y,Z)$ and brackets
$$
[X,Y]=Z,\; [X,Z]=-2X,\; [Y,Z]=2Y.
$$
Then $[[X,Z],[Y,Z]]=-4Z$, but $[[X,Y],Z]=0$.